# Why curl cannot coonect to OpenDJ with a self signed certificate

Tags: curl, ssl, opendj

Can somebody tell me why curl in not working with ldaps and self signed certificate?

I have an Opendj directory server listening on ldaps port 636 and I am trying to connect to it from a remote server using curl and opendj's self signed certificate:

[root@myserver]# /usr/bin/curl -v -k --cacert /tmp/opendj.cer  ldaps://a.b.c.d/dc=example,dc=com

and this is the error message I get:

- About to connect() to a.b.c.d port 636 (#0)
- Trying a.b.c.d... connected
- Connected to a.b.c.d (a.b.c.d) port 636 (#0)
- LDAP local: LDAP Vendor = OpenLDAP ; LDAP Version = 20423
- LDAP local: ldaps://a.b.c.d:636/dc=example,dc=com
- LDAP local: trying to establish encrypted connection
- LDAP local: ldap_simple_bind_s Can't contact LDAP server
- Closing connection #0
  curl: (38) LDAP local: ldap_simple_bind_s Can't contact LDAP server

[root@myserver]#/usr/bin/curl -V
curl 7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.12.9.0 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.2.2
Protocols: tftp ftp telnet dict ldap ldaps http file https ftps scp sftp 
Features: GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM SSL libz

Please not that it works over ldap:

[root@myserver]# /usr/bin/curl -v  ldap://a.b.c.d/dc=example,dc=com
* About to connect() to a.b.c.d port 389 (#0)
*   Trying a.b.c.d... connected
* Connected to a.b.c.d (a.b.c.d) port 389 (#0)
* LDAP local: LDAP Vendor = OpenLDAP ; LDAP Version = 20423
* LDAP local: ldap://a.b.c.d/dc=example,dc=com
* LDAP local: trying to establish cleartext connection
DN: dc=example,dc=com
    dc=example,dc=com

```
objectClass: domain
objectClass: top
```

- Closing connection #0

Thanks,
S.E

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, it is because the SSL layer is enable to agree on a common cipher suite between the client and the server. If you enable SSL debugging on the server side, or in the client side, you should be able to get a more detailed reason of the error. 
You might want to check http://ludopoitou.wordpress.com/2011/06/29/opendj-troubleshooting-ldap-ssl-connections/.

Regards,

Ludovic

Comment: Hi Ludovic, this is what I get on the server side: [07/Nov/2013:14:45:23 +0000] DISCONNECT conn=1 reason="I/O Error" msg="An IO error occurred while reading a request from the client: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate". Please note that I am using the same certificate to connect to the same opendj from OpenAM running inside JBoss and authentication works.

Answer (score 0):

Most SSL tools make an attempt to verify the certificates of the peers they connect to. Basically they check if it is signed by an authority they already trust and curl does not like something about one of the certs. For self signed certificates on the machine you are connecting to this verification often fails.

Curl has a command line option that can help though, `--insecure`

Try something like this:

```
curl --url scp://191.168.0.99/etc/config/wireless.conf -u <username>:<password> --pass --insecure -s > C:\wireless.conf
```

You'll need to substitute your URL, credentials and file names but the parameters essentially tell curl to skip the peer verification of the certificate and just accept it and use password authentication. This completely bypasses a big part of the security SSL was designed to provide but I believe it still encrypts the transfer. As far as I know the only other alternatives are to get a certificate curl likes and that verifies installed on the source host, or find and use the root cert that signed the current source cert in a form that curl likes.